# regex issue for interpolate setting in underscore.js

Tags: regex, templates, underscore.js, client-side, underscore.js-templating

I have following `regex` and `template` for `underscore.js` templates.

the problem is that the regex for `interpolate` is not working properly, what will be correct regex?

**Regex**

```
var settings = {
    evaluate: /\{\{\#([\s\S]+?)\}\}/g,
    interpolate: /\{\{[a-zA-Z](.+?)\}\}/g
};
```

**Template**

```
{{# if ( item ) { }}
    {{ item.title }}
{{# } }}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all the terms, but your match in `interpolate` begins with an alphabet character, whereas `{{ item.title }}` begins with a whitespace. Maybe you could use `/\{\{\s[a-zA-Z](.+?)\}\}/g`? Note that this matches `{{ item.title }}` but captures `tem.title`. To capture `.title`, you will need to use `/\{\{\s[a-zA-Z]+(.+?)\}\}/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template compiler will use the *last* capture group in the expressions to build the JavaScript form of the template. In your case, the `interpolate` will (as noted by Jerry) ignore the first alphabetic character so `{{ab}}` will end up looking for `b` in the template parameters. Your regex also doesn't account for leading whitespace. You'd want something more like this:

```
/\{\{\s*([a-zA-Z](?:.+?))\s*\}\}/g
```

or better, just leave out the original group instead of converting it to a non-capturing group:

```
/\{\{\s*([a-zA-Z].+?)\s*\}\}/g
```

Or even better, get right to the heart of the problem and say exactly what you mean:

```
/\{\{([^#].*?)\}\}/g
```

I think the problem that led you to your original regex is that `interpolate` is checked before `evaluate`; that order makes sense when `interpolate` is looking for `<%= ... %>` and `evaluate` is looking for `<% ... %>` (i.e. the default delimiters are being used). In your case, you need a bit of extra `[^#]` trickery to get around the regex checking order.

Similarly, we can simplify your `evaluate` regex:

```
/\{\{#(.+?)\}\}/g
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/V6rv2/

I'd also recommend that you add an `escape` pattern for completeness.

Comment: thanks a lot, before your reply, I tried fixing regex myself and got `/\{\{([^#][\s\S].+?)\}\}/g` working ;) but now I replaced it with yours `/\{\{([^#].*?)\}\}/g`. and yes I am also using `/\{\{\{(.+?)\}\}\}/g` for `escape`.